# как поместить текст в рамку с изображением?

Tags: html, css

Должно быть так:

[image: скрин1]

Но у меня это выглядит так:

[image: скрин2]

В чём проблема? Код:

```css
.films__gallery-item {
    margin-right: 20px;
    width: 280px;
    height: 434px;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    gap: 16px;
}

.films__image {
    position: relative;
    background: #333;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.films__gallery-item-desc{
    opacity:0;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, 0);
  transition: 0.5s;
  width:98%;
  font-size:22px;
  background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);  
  padding:10px 5px;
  color:#fff;
}

.films__gallery-item:hover .films__gallery-item-desc{
    opacity: 1;
}

.films__gallery-caption {
    margin: 0;
    width: 280px;
    color: #333;
    font-family: Rubik;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<div class="films__gallery-item">
                    <img src="img/picture.png" class="films__image">
                    <div class="films__gallery-item-desc">
                        <p>Фильм повествует о череде событий, произошедших в Голливуде в 1969 году, на закате его «золотого века».
                            Известный актер Рик Далтон и его дублер Клифф Бут пытаются найти свое место в стремительно меняющемся мире
                            киноиндустрии.</p>
                    </div>
                    <p class="films__gallery-caption">Однажды... в Голливуде</p>
                </div>
```